# How can I bootstrap Dojo 1.7 in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, dojo

I've looked at the dojo-node module (https://github.com/agebrock/dojo-node) and the author says that Dojo 1.7 will support Node.js natively.

There is a configNode.js file in Dojo 1.7, but I'm not sure how to use it to have Dojo up and running.

http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0b1/dojo-release-1.7.0b1/dojo/_base/

Can somebody point me into the right direction? Perhaps show me a small example also?

Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: As a side-note I would recommend against using client-side frameworks on the server. Arguably using `Dojo` is not as bad as `jQuery` but it's still pretty bad. Browse the [`npm`](http://npmjs.org/) for libraries that are _designed_ to solve your problem on node.js

Comment: You are probably right, but Dojo has some nice features and I just wanted to see how they're behaving on Node.js. I have been impressed with Dave Glass (yahoo) 's presentation on using YUI with Node, just wanted to meddle a bit with Dojo & Node.

Comment: It's possible but it's far from optimum. As nice as YUI3 with node was I wouldn't recommend it. Your basically going to have to write all the boot strapping yourself :)

Comment: @Raynos - That may be true, but it's also *very* useful to be able to run unit tests for code that doesn't touch the DOM from a shell.

Comment: @lawnsea sorry why do you need Dojo to run unit tests? There are plenty of node specific unit testing libraries.

Comment: @Raynos - I'm sorry, I should have been clear.  I'm talking about running using node to run client-side tests from a shell.  This is really nice when working on client-side code that doesn't need a DOM, such as pubsub.

Comment: @lawnsea you can just use zombie or phantom for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution, although it may look tricky since I can't search out any official examples, I have to read the source and work it out:

1. Assume dojo is under `/home/root/dojoroot/dojo/dojo.js`
2. Create `/home/root/mynode/test.js` with content:

   ```
   dojoConfig = {packages:[{name: 'test', location: '../../mynode'}]};
   require('../dojoroot/dojo/dojo');
   ```
3. Create `/home/root/mynode/main.js` with content:

   ```
   define(['dojo/date'], function(date){
       console.log('Hi ' + date.getTimezoneName(new Date()) + ', welcome to NodeJS!');
   });
   ```
4. $> node /home/root/mynode/test.js load=test

Comment: How does that magically work. What injects `define` into global scope?

Comment: @Raynos - the Dojo loader does so in `dojo.js`.  See https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/dojo.js

Comment: @lawnsea I hoped it didn't inject things into global scope :(

Comment: @Raynos - It only injects those symbols reserved by the CommonJS AMD spec: `define` and `require`.

Comment: @lawnsea please tell me it doesn't overwrite the node.js `require`